# How to use multiple OR statements efficiently

Tags: php, mysql, logic

I want to ignore multiple database tables that are empty.
Is there a more effecient way of doing this instead of using allot of OR statements like in my example:

`if($row['title'] != '' || $row['title'] != NULL || $row['overview'] != '' || $row['overview'] != NULL)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [empty()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):

```
if(!empty($row['title']) and !empty($row['overview']))
{
    print "Do something";
}
```

---

The following values are considered to be `empty`:

```
"" (an empty string)
0 (0 as an integer)
0.0 (0 as a float)
"0" (0 as a string)
NULL
FALSE
array() (an empty array)
$var; (a variable declared, but without a value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to php loose comparison when using `==`, according to [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php), `'' == NULL`, you can write only `if($row['title'] != NULL || $row['overview'] != NULL)`, which is twice shorter.